# programa que inscreve pessoas em uma lista

Tags: python

alguém consegue explicar o erro?

```
quantidadePessoas = int(input('quantas pessoas estarão na festa?'))

lista = []

for pessoa in range(quantidadePessoas):
    nome = input('inscreva uma pessoa')
    lista[pessoa] = 'olá ' + nome + ', seja bem vindo\n'

print(lista)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma `list` (lista) em Python não funciona como se costumam usar os vetores ou "arrays" em C e outras linguagens. Em particular, ela é criada vazia (ou a partir de uma outra sequência) - e você vai acrescentando novos elementos a medida que precisa.

Ou seja: ela não é criada com um tamanho inicial fixo. E isso é o que causa o problema no seu programa. A linha `lista[pessoa] = ...` está corretíssima para *alterar* o conteúdo da lista na posição `pessoa`. O problema é que essa posição ainda não existe - então o seu programa para com um `IndexError`.

A solução é, invés de tentar alterar o conteúdo da `lista` na posição `pessoa`, simplesmente chamar o método das `list` de Python para incluir *um novo* elemento ao final da lista. Esse método é o `.append(<elemento>)`.

O seu programa ficaria assim:

```
quantidadePessoas = int(input('quantas pessoas estarão na festa?'))

    lista = []

    for pessoa in range(quantidadePessoas):
        nome = input('inscreva uma pessoa')
        lista.append(f'olá {nome}, seja bem vindo\n')

    print(lista)
```

(eu também troquei o uso do "+" para concatenar texto por uma "f string" - que permite o uso de variáveis direto dentro das aspas - isso fica mais simples de digitar e mais legível - mas note a letra `f` antes das aspas . Isso só funciona do Python 3.6 pra frente)

Um outro jeito - mas não é o normal em Python, seria forçar a criação de um elemento da lista para cada pessoa que você vai incluir, antes do `for` - isso pode ser feito criando uma lista com um único elemento, e usando o operador de multiplicação `*` para "somar essa lista com ela mesma" N vezes - e assim ter uma lista com o comprimento necessário. O início do programa ficaria assim (e aí o restante do código que você escreveu funcionaria como está):

```
quantidadePessoas = int(input('quantas pessoas estarão na festa?'))

lista = [''] * quantidadePessoas
...
```

(Aqui fica uma dica importante para suas futuras perguntas: sempre inclua o erro que o Python imprime - chamamos de "traceback" - junto com o seu código com problema. Nesse caso, o programa é curto e é fácil ver o que acontece - mas em geral o traceback descreve exatamente *onde* está o erro e *o quê* aconteceu, que é importantíssimo em um program a mais complexo)

Comment: Ótima explicação..